# Retrieving record function in generic SOP

Tags: haskell, ghc-generics

In [`Sum of Products`](https://www.andres-loeh.de/TrueSumsOfProducts/) approach, how would one retrieve the record function? An example code below with record datatype (`ghc 7.10.3`):

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
import qualified GHC.Generics as GHC
import Generics.SOP
data Rec = Rec { frec :: Int, srec :: Maybe String}
  deriving (Show, GHC.Generic)

instance Generic Rec     -- empty
instance HasDatatypeInfo Rec
```

Let us see `DataTypeInfo`  at ghci prompt:

```
*Main> datatypeInfo (Proxy :: Proxy Rec)
ADT "Main" "Rec" (Record "Rec" (FieldInfo "frec" :* (FieldInfo "srec" :* Nil)) :* Nil)
```

We see that `frec` and `srec` are both of type `FieldInfo` which has a constructor `FieldInfo` which takes the `fieldName` as string. So, I don't see any way to get the actual functions `frec :: Rec -> Int` and `srec :: Rec -> Maybe String`. I also looked at [show example](https://github.com/well-typed/basic-sop/blob/master/src/Generics/SOP/Show.hs) but it doesn't use record functions.

Will appreciate pointers on how to get the record functions (could be HList of type `HList '[(Rec -> Int), (Rec -> Maybe String)]`)).

**Addendum to the question**

I am tied up in the type knots about how to get the functions out of the projections using the approach user2407038 has laid out. So, I will like to add to the question further: how do we build a function like below using `SOP` approach on `Rec` constructor - we use both record field name as well as the function here:

```
[ ("frec" ++) . show . frec, ("srec" ++) . show . srec]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `generics-sop` library implements general combinators for working with sums of products, so you should write such a function using those combinators.

There is one issue - `generics-sop` does not have any information about records vs. constructors on the type level, so your function will be still be partial (unless you go digging in the GHC generics `Rep`).

For this example I'll just go with the partial function route.

First, you need this datatype:

```
data (:*:) f g x = f x :*: g x deriving (Show, Eq, Ord, Functor)
```

It seems like it should be included in the library, but it isn't (or I can't find it).

The type of the function will be

```
recordSelectors :: forall t r . (Code t ~ '[ r ], Generic t, HasDatatypeInfo t) 
                => Proxy t -> Maybe (NP (FieldInfo :*: (->) t) r)
```

The constraint `Code t ~ '[ r ]` simply says that the sum of productions representation of `t` is a singleton list (one constructor). The return type is (maybe) a product over the list `r` (the list of record field types) where there is a `FieldInfo x` and a `t -> x` for each type `x` in `r`.

One implementation is

```
  case datatypeInfo (Proxy :: Proxy t) of 
    ADT _ _ (Record _ fields :* Nil) -> Just $ 
      hzipWith (\nm (Fn prj) -> nm :*: (unI . prj . K . (\(Z x) -> x) . unSOP . from)) 
               fields 
               projections 
    _ -> Nothing
```

Here the function determines in the given datatype is really a record, and otherwise returns `Nothing`. If it is a record, zip togther the record fields and the `projections` (defined by the library), which defines projections for an arbitrary generic product, which is essentially just `NP '[ Code Rec -> Int, Code Rec -> Maybe String ]` for your type. All that is left is to compose the `from` function with each projection to get the "real" projections. The rest (`Fn`, `unSOP`, etc.) are just identities.

---

Since it turns out you just want the record projection functions, sans function names, this is even simpler. And now the function isn't partial - any one constructor type has "record projections".

```
recordSelectors' :: forall t r . (Code t ~ '[ r ], Generic t) 
                 => Proxy t -> NP ((->) t) r
recordSelectors' _ = hmap (\(Fn prj) -> unI . prj . K . (\(Z x) -> x) . unSOP . from) 
                          projections
```

Comment: Won't getting the projection itself and ignoring the fieldInfo be sufficient to retrieve record function? As you said, type of `projections` here is `NP '[Code Rec -> Int, Code Rec -> Maybe String]`. Also, `Rep a = SOP I (Code a))`. Pairing that with `to` should give us `a` which is `Rec -> Int`, a function, no? That is why I am confused about need for `:*:`. Will appreciate further insights here.

Comment: Also, how did you calculate the type of `projections`, especially in `ghci`? That step will be very helpful in experimenting.

Comment: Oh sorry - I thought you wanted the functions *and* their names. Indeed, you could just have `NP ((->) t) r` - that's just the functions. Also, I didn't calculate the type in GHCi - just in my head, based on my understanding of the general type. But you could ask ghci, of course, with e.g. `:t projections :: (Code Rec ~ '[ xs ]) => NP (Projection f xs) xs` - the type is the general type of `projections`, and the constraint is the same one used in the question - which says `:: NP (Projection f '[Int, Maybe String]) '[Int, Maybe String]`.

Comment: Will appreciate also adding how to get the functions out of it. Type after `fromJust` is `NP ((->) Rec) '[Int, Maybe String]`. However, `Rep a` requires `SOP I (Code a)`. So, `NP ((-> Rec))  '[Int, Maybe String]` needs to be converted to `NP I '[ (Rec -> Int), (Rec -> Maybe String)]`. I haven't been able to figure out the type knots here yet.

Comment: The types `NP ((->) Rec) '[Int, Maybe String]` and `NP I '[ (Rec -> Int), (Rec -> Maybe String)]` are isomorphic. However, the latter cannot be easily expressed in a general way. It could be `NP I (Map ((->) Rec) '[ Int, Maybe String])` for example - but `Map` here is a type function, meaning it is non-injective. To "map" over a list with `generics-sop`, you are *supposed* to use the `f` parameter of `NS` and `NP`. You should simply work with the former type - the latter type will not really allow you to use the combinators provided by the library.

Comment: oh, ok, so how would you work with `NP ((->) Rec)` then to get the functions out? FYI, I have added an addendum to my question above, in case you haven't noticed that. I looked in `generics-sop` documentation for combinator functions for `NP f` but couldn't figure out yet how to do what I asked in the addendum. Learning process :) Appreciate your patient explanations.

Comment: Depends on exactly what you want to do with your functions! If you want to do something with each function, use `hmap`, `hap` or the like, which returns another `NP`. If you need to pass each record projection to some higher-order function `q`, for example, you can write `hmap q (recordSelectors ..)`. If you need a single one of those functions, you have to decide a way to pick one. For example to arbitrarily select the first one you can use `hd` (which is a type error if called on an empty product).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107581/discussion-between-sal-and-user2407038).